# String in function call treated differently than string defined in function - strange error

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, dom

I am trying to make a function that can edit the dom on click, that I can pass different elements into, too reduce duplicate code. However when i pass an id in as string in a function it will not grab the dom element. However if I use the same text in a string declared in the function it will. I have tried console logging the output and using that same string defined by me, in the dom request and that works however variable defined in the function prototype do not it seens unexplainable to me.

e.x will work var x = document.getElementById('button1').style.display="block";

but var x = document.getElementById(str1).style.display="block"; will not, where  str is taken from funtion header, even tho str console.logs("button1");
however if i declare a variable r = "button1" inside the function 
var x = document.getElementById(r).style.display="block"; - this will work
why are string passed into the function treated differently

example fiddle illustrating the problem
https://jsfiddle.net/peacefulgoldfish/wpvyu5fr/20/

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="/js/lib/dummy.js"

  ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    #div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

#button1{
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:blue;
}
  </style>
  <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->

  <script type="text/javascript">




function switchv(){
switchbutton("'block'", "'button1'");
}

function switchbutton(str, str2){
console.log(str2)
r = str2;

    var x = document.getElementById(r).style.display="block";

}



</script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="div1" onclick="switchv();">

</button>

<div id="button1">

</div>

  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: ""
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you quoting twice: `switchbutton("'block'", "'button1'");`?

Comment: There is an error in your function call. `switchbutton("'block'", "'button1'");` should be `switchbutton("block", "button1");`. Should be either double quotes or single quotes. Not both.

Comment: that doesnt work, the reason i have 2 quotations is because 1 of them is automatically removed after being passed in and DOM requires quotes on the element id. if you pass in single quotes it will do nothing

Comment: @davej that's not correct: here's a fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/togu9drh/

Comment: I see thank you for clarifiying, I guess I thought it was more picky with syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around "'buttton1'".

This function will work:

```
function switchv(){
    switchbutton("block", "button1");
}
```

**Edit:** It seems jsfiddle doesn't like the `onclick=switchv()`, although inside a standalone html page it works.

Setting the onclick function inside the JavaScript portion seems to work, though. Here's the modified version: https://jsfiddle.net/wpvyu5fr/40/

Comment: that doesnt work, the reason i have 2 quotations is because 1 of them is automatically removed after being passed in and DOM requires quotes on the element id

Comment: @davej I tested the above and it works. The dom does NOT require quotes around the element id. You put quotes around literals.

Comment: can you post your code, because I copy pasted your code in and it does not work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/peacefulgoldfish/wpvyu5fr/26/

Comment: @davej In the fiddle it says `switchv` is not defined. I tested using a single HTML page, I'll update my answer with the code

Comment: okay thank, It seems that javascript alot more flexible than I expected. I figured out that the reason switchv is undefined has something to do with the way jsfiddle call it. If I use your format and call it in a html script tag I can get it to workm or using the new method your wrote

Answer (score 0):

Going off the link to the fiddle that you sent it seems that you called the str argument in the switchbutton function str1, they need to be the same. Also the double quotes are not necessary.

```
function switchbutton(str, str2){
  var x = document.getElementById(str2);
  x.style.display = str;
}
```

Comment: good catch on that, but if use this method the dom still will not update atleast when i try it